# Google map inside another fragment - Function like onLocationChanged is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-gps

My previous question [Google map inside another fragment - Error when calling getMapAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458584/google-map-inside-another-fragment-error-when-calling-getmapasync) was answered. The google map is showing and the getMapAsync is now working.

And I'm now finding the solution to the other functions like

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {...}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {...}
```

Note:
I'm trying to convert a google map activity to work inside a fragment that will be called in NavigationView.

`samplemapFragment.java`

```
package  com.sample.samplemap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;

public class samplemapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;

    MapView mapView;

    View mView;

    public samplemapFragment() {
        Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_track_travel, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);

        if (mapView != null) {
            // Initialise the MapView
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

`fragment_sample_map.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context="com.sample.samplemap.samplemapFragment"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this code showing map in navigationView? if you want to get location on location changelistener then you put your locationchange code in activity class.

Answer (score 0):

OnLocationChanged is not a method tied to a GoogleMap, it is actually related to the LocationListener (or LocationClient) API. To get notifications for OnLocationChanged, you will have to register a 'Listener' which will poll the device's location and when it registers a change, will trigger the OnLocationChanged method.

You can find a comprehensive guide with examples here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Good luck!

Comment: i have a code that is working. It includes the onLocationChanged function. Now im finding the way how to make it work inside another fragment because it will be called in NavigationView and it caused most of the function not to work as it suppose to do