# Android google maps inside fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I know that there are a lot of questions about maps inside a fragment on stackoverflow, but all of them are outdated and are not working for me.. So, I am trying to implement google maps inside a fragment, the map is displayed, but I cannot use setMyLocationEnabler(true), or add markers, or anything.. Here's my code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map);
    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.location_map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    }
    if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                if (googleMap != null) {
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

}
```

My API key is correctly added in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="-----------------------------------"/>

</application>
```

And here's the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mk.com.urban.urbanrider.MapFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/location_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have google play services dependencies in by build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':volley')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I really have no idea what to do next, I've tried everything...

Comment: You should double check your search, today I was looking to use a G map on fragment... after 2 hours I got it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35460657/1332549). If it help you, told me, I will add a link to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried and I see no problems to use map inside a custom fragment.

Activity class with custom fragment:

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static class WrapFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrap_demo_fragment, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.save_state_demo);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.map_wrap, new WrapFragment(), "qwerty_tag")
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

activity layout save_state_demo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1337" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_wrap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

your custom fragment layout wrap_demo_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That's all you need.